# COM object fail, class not registered error, WMEncBasicEdit

Tags: c#, audio, com, regsvr32, wma

I have to cut WMA file from start position to end position. I'm trying to use WMEncoder. I've installed Windows Media Encoder SDK 9 and added a reference to WMEncoder lib for my project. But when I'm trying to create a new instance of WMEncBasicEdit class Visual Studio throws exception 80040154. Where is my fault?

Comment: Using the 64-bit version of Windows?  Set the project's Platform target setting to "x86".

Comment: It is already done, I had the same problems with other manually compiled COM objects

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to see where it looks in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 80040154 indicates that the COM class is not registered.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't be registered; this is usually handled by the installer.  On my machine, from looking in the registry I can see that class is implemented in the following file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wmpencen.dll
```

Can you see if you have that file installed?  If it is, you can try registering it:

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\wmpencen.dll
```

Or rerun the SDK installer (assuming it installs this file) and check for errors.

Comment: It didn't help. I've registered it, regsvr32 showed me success window, but nothing changed. I've reinstalled WMencoder SDK and even rebooted system but nothing changed too.

Comment: we need the other file to be registered: wmenceng.dll